# C# Linq Lambda elements count

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a problem with `LINQ` and it is that I do not know how to solve the problem of counting the elements with certain conditions.

Explanation:

I have the following set of elements in an object of type `List<Dispositivo> _devices`

```
{
    root: [{
            dispositivo: 413,
            variables: [{
                    name: "Ignition",
                    value: false,
                    type: "Boolean",
                    unit: "boolean",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:06:36.0000000Z"
                }, {
                    name: "Speed",
                    value: 0,
                    type: "Double",
                    unit: "M/S",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:06:54.0000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            dispositivo: 418,
            variables: [{
                    name: "Ignition",
                    value: true,
                    type: "Boolean",
                    unit: "boolean",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:08:19.0000000Z"
                }, {
                    name: "Speed",
                    value: 19.3888888888889,
                    type: "Double",
                    unit: "M/S",
                    utc: "2021-05-06T21:08:19.0000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            dispositivo: 419,
            variables: [{
                    name: "Ignition",
                    value: true,
                    type: "Boolean",
                    unit: "boolean",
                    utc: "2021-03-22T20:20:22.0000000Z"
                },{
                    name: "Speed",
                    value: 0,
                    type: "Double",
                    unit: "M/S",
                    utc: "2021-05-04T16:19:06.0000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Classes:

```
class Variables 
{
    string name,
    object value,
    type    string,
    unit    string,
    utc     string
}

class Dispositivos
{
    int device ,
    Lis<Variables> variables 
}
```

I wrote the following code to try to count the variables of this in the following condition:

Count the devices whose "Ignition" variable is set to "true" and whose "Speed" variable is greater than or equal to 5.

I wrote this but it does not work for me it gives me errors in the edition.

```
var sobrevelocidad = _devices.Count(d => d.variables.Where(s => s.name == "Speed" && s.value.ToString() == "true"));
```

[image]

If anyone beats more on `LINQ` and `LAMBDA` you can give me a hand with that.

Comment: You should include the error message in your question, it will help you get an answer sooner.

Comment: It would be most appreciated if you could post of the code as valid C#. Please make it easy for us to provide an answer.

Comment: So you have `Dispositivos` and `Variables`, and you ask us how to `Count the devices whose ...`. Consider to edit your question and tell us what `Devices` are.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Count method needs a lambda expression that returns a Boolean value.

For example:

```
var sobrevelocidad = _devices.Count(d => 
    d.variables.Any(s => s.name == "Speed" && s.value >= 5) &&
    d.variables.Any(s => s.name == "Ignition" && s.value.ToString() == "true")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of the predicate expression you pass to the `Count()` function must return a `boolean` where as `d.variables.Where()` returns the list of elements that match the condition. Use `Any()` instead of `Where()` to check for the presence of a record.

```
var sobrevelocidad = _devices.Count(d => d.variables.Any(s => s.name == "Speed" && s.value.ToString() == "true"));
```

However in your case you want to check for the presence of two variables in the list for a record to match and be counted which means a call to `Any()` for both The "Speed" variable and the "Ignition" variable.

```
var count = _devices.Count(d => d.variables.Any(s => s.name == "Speed" && s.value > 5) && d.variables.Any(s => s.name = "Ignition" && s.value));
```